# Fibonacci numbers are O(n), faulty induction

Tags: induction, asymptotics, fibonacci-numbers

I'm currently working through the Book "Data Structures & Algorithms in Python" by Goodrich et al. in self-study. I have no "profound" mathematics background and am stuck at one of the end-of-chapter excercises, which asks to point out the mistake that was made within the following induction:

Fibonacci numbers here starting with $F(1)=1$, $F(2)=2$. Claim: $F(n)$ is $O(n)$.

Base cases $(n\leq2)$: $F(1)=1$ and $F(2)=2$.

Induction step $(n\gt2)$: Assume claim true for $n'<n$. Consider $n$. $F(n)=F(n-2)+F(n-1)$. By induction hypothesis, $F(n-2)$ is $O(n-2)$ and $F(n-1)$ is $O(n-1)$. Thus, $F(n)$ is $O((n-2)+(n-1))$ since $d(n)$ is $O(f(n))$ and $e(n)$ is $O(g(n))$ implies $d(n)+e(n)$ is $O(f(n)+g(n))$.

The book also gives the hint to rewrite the inductive assumption/hypothesis in terms of the formal definition of big-$O$, which I did:

There is a real constant $c\gt0$ and an integer constant $n_0\geq1$ such that $F(n)\leq c*n$, for $n$ with $n_0\leq n\lt n'$.

With this hypothesis, the inequalities $F(n-2)\leq c*n$ and $F(n-1)\leq c*n$ with an appropriate constant $c$ should hold. By adding these, you can deduce that $F(n)$ is $O(n)$ from that point on.

Obviously, there is some mistake but I am unable to find it. I can just guess that it might be about big-$O$ requiring an $n_0$ such that the inequality is valid for **all** $n\geq n_0$, or that there must be at least one **fixed** constant $c$.

Comment: The problem is that the implied constant in the big-$O$ will grow with $n$. You can see that you will have $2c \cdot n$ as an upper bound for $F(n)$.

Comment: @Gary Thank you for your answer! Could you outline how I would show that $c$ grows with $n$ and that $2c*n$ is an upper bound? How can you make sure that your constant(s) $c$ in the base case(s) are the same c that is used in the inductive assumption in general, when proving $O(n)$-statements by induction?

Comment: @Gary $2c*n$ is an upper bound for $F(n)$ because $F(n)=F(n-1)+F(n-2)\leq c*n+c*n=2c*n$, right? Why would it not work to "stuff" the factor $2$ into the $n$, since $O(2n)=O(n)$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to show a statement of the form $\exists c : \forall n : P(c, n)$. You seem to show by induction that $\forall n : \exists c : P(c, n)$.

Maybe you misunderstand the fact that "$f = O(n)$ and $g = O(n)$ implies $f+g = O(n)$". The hypothesis "$f = O(n)$" is a statement about the function $f$, and to apply it you already need to know that $\forall n : \exists c : P(c, n)$, that is, **for all $n$**.

Comment: Thank you! "and to apply it you already need to know that $∀n:∃c:P(c,n)$, that is, for all $n$" But wouldn't this mean that you can't prove $O(n)$-claims with induction in general? How would you phrase the inductive assumption, when you can't assume it to be true for all $n'<n$?

Comment: @Ruperrrt Indeed, you can't prove them by induction, or at least not directly. Basically, induction proofs only give you propositions that begin with "$\forall n:$". Of course, once you have a guess of what constant $c$ could work, you can try to prove $F(n) \leq cn$ by induction (for this fixed value of $c$), and you will have shown that $ \exists c : \forall n : F(n) \leq cn$.

Comment: Ahh, so this is the crux of the error in the induction! But how can you find/guess such a c? The excercise right before the one this post deals with asks to show that n lines that are not parallel determine Θ(n2) intersection points assuming each intersection is unique to a pair of lines. I started with a base case of n=2 and just stated  just stated 1/4∗22≤p(n)=1≤1/4∗22. That is, I picked c1=c2=1/4. But I can't be sure that the inductive assumption holds for the same c. How would I pick it that it works for both, the base cases and the inductive step?

Comment: There's no general method, but you could find a $c$ by writing a sketch of a proof and seeing what $c$ needs to be for it to work. In your example with the lines: Suppose you've shown that $pn \geq c n^2$, and you wish to show that $p(n+1) \geq c (n+1)^2$. By adding a point you add $n$ intersection points, so you know that $p(n+1) = p(n) + n$. You would be done if the constant $c$ is such that $cn^2 + n \geq c(n+1)^2$. That is, if $n \geq (2n+1)c$, or $\frac{n}{2n+1} \geq c$. So as long as $c$ is less than $\frac{n}{2n+1}$ *for all $n$*, your proof by induction (for $p(n)\geq cn^2$) will work.

Comment: Thank you so much for your effort! This will help me a lot.

Comment: You're welcome, I'm glad to help.